# Block keyboard and mouse events from reaching a specific application

Tags: c++, windows, hook

Let's say  an application that we do not have control of   installs some kind of global keyboard or mouse hook. Is it possible to block those events reaching to this application?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  You can make a keyboard and mouse *driver* which can process the keyboard and mouse events, and replace them or consume them or emit other events or pass them thru (possibly modifying their state).

Comment: Are you asking as a user, or as a software programmer?

Comment: Ha, I was just going to say it's not possible, but @Eljay is right - you can block them if you manage to consume them first. But it would depend if the hooks are a stack or a queue - i.e. is the last registered the first to process? And is it possible to prevent propagation (JS event listeners for example don't allow it but I think Windows does).

Comment: @Eljay  what do you mean  
-consume
-emit other events
-pass them through

can you describe by naming some functions to do that?

Comment: I wouldn't be able to describe is sufficiently in a comment.  Or even in an answer.  I'd need to write an entire book.  Fortunately, there are entire books already written on the topic, and there's a lot of free information on MSDN.

Comment: can you recommend pls ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to block input from applications that are using LowLevelKeyboard(or Mouse) hooks its fairly easy.

But if you want to block input from reaching games or a lot of applications, you'd have to write a filter driver. Most games don't use hooks, and instead use API's such as DirectInput, or XInput, which I believe talk to the HID drivers directly.
There are 2 projects I know about that have done this, [HidHide](https://github.com/nefarius/HidHide) and [HidGuardian](https://github.com/nefarius/HidGuardian).

As for blocking hooks, I wrote up a quick program to do that.
It works by installing its own keyboard hook, checking to see if the application you want to block input to is the foreground window, and then if it is the foreground window, the hook returns instead of calling the next hook.
It would be easy to modify to include mouse inputs as well.
I thought it would only work if you ran the program before the application you wish you block, but it doesn't seem to matter.

There are a couple problems to this approach. Don't be surprised if it doesn't work for most applications, or only partially works for some applications.
I also wrote a test application using WinForms to test blocking, which set a controls text to the current key being pressed. It successfully blocked that, but it did not stop a Textbox from receiving it's input.

- It will block other applications from receiving the hook as well, not just your target.
- It will only block if the application is the foreground window, which probably isn't an issue in most cases, but could be.
- Only blocks the app from having its hook called. If it gets input from anywhere but the hook, the input will reach the application(eg. WinForms textbox).

The blocking happens in `LowLevelKeyboardProc_cb,` the rest is just set-up code to get the handle and setup the hook.

```c
LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc_cb(
_In_ int    nCode,
_In_ WPARAM wParam,
_In_ LPARAM lParam)
{
    HWND fWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
    
    //hBlock is the handle to the process's main window
    if (fWnd != hBlock || nCode < 0)
        return CallNextHookEx(hookId, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    else
        return 0; //Block
}
```

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

void SetHook();
void UninstallHook();
DWORD GetProcessIdFromName(const char* name);
HWND FindTopWindow(DWORD pid);

HWND hBlock;
HHOOK hookId;
DWORD pidBlock;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* processName = argv[1];

    printf("Searching for process \"%s\"...\n", processName);

    while (pidBlock == 0)
    {
        pidBlock = GetProcessIdFromName(processName);
    }

    std::cout << "Found\n";

    //Allow window to initialize.
    Sleep(1000);

    std::cout << "Searching for main window handle...\n";
    
    hBlock = FindTopWindow(pidBlock);
    
    if (hBlock == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not find Window Handle\n";
        return 0;
    }

    std::cout << "Found\n";
    std::cout << "Installing Hook...\n";

    SetHook();

    std::cout << "Blocking...";  

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc_cb(
    _In_ int    nCode,
    _In_ WPARAM wParam,
    _In_ LPARAM lParam
)
{
    HWND fWnd = GetForegroundWindow();

    if (fWnd != hBlock || nCode < 0)
        return CallNextHookEx(hookId, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    else
        return 0; //Block
}

void SetHook()
{
    HANDLE hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
    HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    hookId = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc_cb, hModule, 0);

    CloseHandle(hProcess);
}

void UninstallHook()
{
    if (hookId == 0)
        return;
    std::cout << "Uninstalling Hook.\n";
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookId);
    hookId = 0;
}

DWORD GetProcessIdFromName(const char* name)
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
    entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

    if (Process32First(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
    {
        while (Process32Next(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
        {
            size_t nChars;
            char szExeFile[64];
            wcstombs_s(&nChars, szExeFile, entry.szExeFile, sizeof(szExeFile));

            if (_stricmp(szExeFile, name) == 0)
            {
                DWORD pid = entry.th32ProcessID;
                CloseHandle(snapshot);
                return pid;
            }
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(snapshot);

    return 0;
}

HWND FindTopWindow(DWORD pid)
{
    std::pair<HWND, DWORD> params = { 0, pid };

    // Enumerate the windows using a lambda to process each window
    BOOL bResult = EnumWindows([](HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) -> BOOL
        {
            auto pParams = (std::pair<HWND, DWORD>*)(lParam);

            DWORD processId;
            if (GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &processId) && processId == pParams->second)
            {
                // Stop enumerating
                SetLastError(-1);
                pParams->first = hwnd;
                return FALSE;
            }

            // Continue enumerating
            return TRUE;
        }, (LPARAM)&params);

    if (!bResult && GetLastError() == -1 && params.first)
    {
        return params.first;
    }

    return 0;
}
```